# How to prove the equality for this summation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Sorry if this is a silly question but I can't remember how to prove the following equality!
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \Bigl(\frac{1-x}{2}\Bigr)^n = (1-x)^n $$

and consequently how to obtain the following sum

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n 2^{2i-n}\binom{n}{i} \Bigl(\frac{1-x}{2}\Bigr)^n = \bigl( \frac{5}{4} \bigr)^n (1-x)^n  $$

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n =\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} =?$$

Comment: It is equivalent to showing that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}=2^n$. And for proving the latter equality, simply compare the expression with the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n
&= \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n \cdot\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\\
&= \frac{(1-x)^n}{2^n}\cdot 2^n\\
&= (1-x)^n
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{2i-n}\binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n
&= \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{2i}\binom{n}{i}\\
&= \left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)^n\cdot\sum_{i=0}^n 4^i\binom{n}{i}\\
&= \left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)^n\cdot\sum_{i=0}^n 4^i1^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}\\
&= (1-x)^n \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \cdot (4+1)^n\\
&= \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n(1-x)^n
\end{align}$$

And as always, *as desired* :)

Comment: Also binomial expansion and realising which parts are constant and can be taken out

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n
&= \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^n \cdot\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\\
&= \frac{(1-x)^n}{2^n}\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}1^i 1^{n-i}}_{=(1+1)^n=2^n}\\
&= (1-x)^n
\end{align}